# unable to get the system service memory and cpu metrics of kubernetes cluster in grafana dashboard using prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, grafana, prometheus

I am trying to monitor my kubernetes cluster metrics using Prometheus and grafana. Here is the [link](https://github.com/bibinwilson/kubernetes-prometheus) which was i followed. Facing the issue with kubernetes-service-endpoints (2/3 up) in my Prometheus dashboard.

[image: Prometheus dashboard]

below is grafana dashboard which is used in this task.

[image: grafana dashboard]

I checked my Prometheus pod logs .It shows the errors like

[image: logs]

Could anybody suggest how to get system services metrics in the above dashboard?

(or)

suggest me the any grafana dashboard name for monitoring the kubernetes cluster using Prometheus?

Answer (score 1):

Check your prometheus.yaml it should have static configs as for prometheus,

```
  static_configs:
  - targets:
    - localhost:9090
```

curl `localhost:9090/metrics` and make sure you're receiving metrics as output

For grafana dashboard, create an org -> prometheus as data source configure prometheus IP:PORT and click on test and confirm connectivity is available.

Open .json file and change the configs according your requirements and import and check.

Comment: Thanks for responding harik. I run the Prometheus service as node port type. I configured as like as you said ip:nodeport in Prometheus.yaml file. I don't have any idea on changing the .json file.Could you please suggest me, for getting the system services memory and cpu usage. every thing fine with remaining metrics.

Comment: To get node level memory, cpu and systemd service metrics you have to deploy node_exporter. Open the .json and change data source name.